# Postgresql port connection issue

Tags: postgresql, psql

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: so, **is** the server running? And yes on which port?

Comment: See here for similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+Is+the+server+running+on+host+%22localhost%22+